# Is Dacron and Glyptal the same polymer?

Tags: polymers

I know Dacron or Terylene is a polymer of ethylene glycol and terephthalic acid . But is Glyptal also a name for Dacron? Glyptal has almost similar monomers.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Polymer Properties Database](http://polymerdatabase.com/polymer%20classes/Alkyd%20Resin.html), Glyptal is a manufacturer of [alkyd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkyd) resins formed from polyhydric alcohols with polybasic acids. Certainly, they might make [polyethylene terephthalate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_terephthalate) as well.